# Drag and Drop an Email from MS Outlook to Eclipse RCP

Tags: java, eclipse, ms-office, integration, desktop

Has anyone got a working solution without some Java/COM-bridge? E.g. process the Email as a file (.msg) rather than locating the data that is referenced in the Clipboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is a solution for your problem: 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaoutlookdd/
It allows to handle outlook items like File objects during drag&drop.

Answer (score 2):

I did make some headway on this sort of thing a few years back using [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org) to extract the contents of an email from .msg files.  I'm pretty sure they have a simple swing explorer / viewer that you can use to examine the structure within the compound document format, but I can't find it right now.

I was able to extract most information that I was interested in but was ultimately wanting to create a mime format version of the message and couldn't extract all the information I needed in a format I could use.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you've already ruled out the tools in "org.eclipse.swt.dnd" for some reason?  There are some examples [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/Clipboard.htm) on how to go about using them, in case you haven't.  If what you really want to do is drag&drop, you're going to have to do some work with those tools.  At that point, really the question becomes, what format is it in on the clipboard, vs in a file, and which is easier to integrate into your app.